# Add text at the end of files name in Total Commander

Tags: total-commander, bulk-rename

am new to TC and I would need to add one text to Files name:

```
CCERTASD_IV_CUSTOMENAME_1234_12345
```

TO

```
CCERTASD_IV_CUSTOMENAME_1234_12345 PV AAAAAA
```

`PV AAAAA` the same for all

means keep the same naming and just add `PV AAAAA`.

All files are pdf files.

Comment: I forget to add that all files are pdf files

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask please have a read of this. In its current state, your question will be closed. Please edit your question once you've understood how the site works.

Comment: Check the rename features.

Answer (score 0):

You have option under Files > Multi-rename tool, or can do it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.
There are different masks, decide what you need.

Also, you will see a preview immediately after choosing one of the masks.

Comment: Thanks all, for prompt reply. But how to add the mask for many file with different name but the same format.

Answer (score 0):

Hit Ctrl+M
into the first field "Rename mask: file name" enter

[N] PV AAAAAA

[N] means use original name then " PV AAAAAA" to add the string for each selected file.